# Hibernate and ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, oracle, spring-data-jpa

I'm developing a Spring Boot application, a REST API.

Until now I was mapping the entities date-times as `LocalDateTime`. But it's required to have the Zone time information, so I guess I should use `ZonedDateTime` insteed. But I'm worried about what zone time is actually used. As the data base field has this format: `2004-12-20 18:00:00` so the zone time is calculated based on the current machine (as it's suggested on the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html)).

To avoid any catastrophy, the zone time that should be used is the one that is configured on data base. **How I could configure the ZonedDateTimes of my entities to take a specific zone time?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the link below you have to globally configure hibernate property `hibernate.jdbc.time_zone` (in hibernate 5)

https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-whats-the-best-way-to-persist-a-zoneddatetime/

Further setting on a specific entity will be ignored as described.